# how to find a li that cointes certain text and hide him and also the next parent sibiling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, find, hide

i have a HTML code:

```
       <li class="item first">
<a class="product-image" title="מדפסת Epson LQ-690" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/mdpst-epson-lq-690.html">
<img width="135" height="135" alt="מדפסת Epson LQ-690" src="http://s5169dbdce2040.img.gostorego.com/809E82/cdn/media/s5/16/9d/bd/ce/20/40/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg">
</a>
<h3 class="product-name">
<a title="מדפסת Epson LQ-690" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/mdpst-epson-lq-690.html">מדפסת Epson LQ-690</a>
</h3>
<div class="price-box">
<span id="product-price-96-widget-new-grid" class="regular-price">
<span class="price" style="display: inline;">0.00 ₪</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="actions" style="display: block;">
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://adcs.gostorego.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FkY3MuZ29zdG9yZWdvLmNvbS8,/product/96/')" title="הוסף לסל" type="button">
<span>
<span>הוסף לסל</span>
</span>
</button>
<ul class="add-to-links">
<li>
<span class="separator">|</span>
<a class="link-compare" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/catalog/product_compare/add/product/96/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FkY3MuZ29zdG9yZWdvLmNvbS8,/">הוסף להשוואה</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<a class="product-image" title="מתג HP 1910-48G Switch" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/mtg-hp-1910-48g-switch.html">
<img width="135" height="135" alt="מתג HP 1910-48G Switch" src="http://s5169dbdce2040.img.gostorego.com/809E82/cdn/media/s5/16/9d/bd/ce/20/40/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg">
</a>
<h3 class="product-name">
<a title="מתג HP 1910-48G Switch" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/mtg-hp-1910-48g-switch.html">מתג HP 1910-48G Switch</a>
</h3>
<div class="price-box">
<span id="product-price-109-widget-new-grid" class="regular-price">
<span class="price">2,431.00 ₪</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="actions" style="display: block;">
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://adcs.gostorego.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FkY3MuZ29zdG9yZWdvLmNvbS8,/product/109/')" title="הוסף לסל" type="button">
<span>
<span>הוסף לסל</span>
</span>
</button>
<ul class="add-to-links">
<li>
<span class="separator">|</span>
<a class="link-compare" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/catalog/product_compare/add/product/109/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FkY3MuZ29zdG9yZWdvLmNvbS8,/">הוסף להשוואה</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item">
<a class="product-image" title="מתג HP E2510-48 Switch" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/mtg-hp-e2510-48-switch.html">
<img width="135" height="135" alt="מתג HP E2510-48 Switch" src="http://s5169dbdce2040.img.gostorego.com/809E82/cdn/media/s5/16/9d/bd/ce/20/40/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg">
</a>
<h3 class="product-name">
<a title="מתג HP E2510-48 Switch" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/mtg-hp-e2510-48-switch.html">מתג HP E2510-48 Switch</a>
</h3>
<div class="price-box">
<span id="product-price-110-widget-new-grid" class="regular-price">
<span class="price" style="display: inline;">0.00 ₪</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="actions" style="display: block;">
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://adcs.gostorego.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FkY3MuZ29zdG9yZWdvLmNvbS8,/product/110/')" title="הוסף לסל" type="button">
<span>
<span>הוסף לסל</span>
</span>
</button>
<ul class="add-to-links">
<li>
<span class="separator">|</span>
<a class="link-compare" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/catalog/product_compare/add/product/110/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FkY3MuZ29zdG9yZWdvLmNvbS8,/">הוסף להשוואה</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
<li class="item last">
<a class="product-image" title="מתג HP E2510-24G Switch" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/mtg-hp-e2510-24g-switch.html">
<img width="135" height="135" alt="מתג HP E2510-24G Switch" src="http://s5169dbdce2040.img.gostorego.com/809E82/cdn/media/s5/16/9d/bd/ce/20/40/catalog/product/cache/1/small_image/135x/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/images/catalog/product/placeholder/small_image.jpg">
</a>
<h3 class="product-name">
<a title="מתג HP E2510-24G Switch" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/mtg-hp-e2510-24g-switch.html">מתג HP E2510-24G Switch</a>
</h3>
<div class="price-box">
<span id="product-price-111-widget-new-grid" class="regular-price">
<span class="price">2,696.00 ₪</span>
</span>
</div>
<div class="actions" style="display: block;">
<button class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('http://adcs.gostorego.com/checkout/cart/add/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FkY3MuZ29zdG9yZWdvLmNvbS8,/product/111/')" title="הוסף לסל" type="button">
<span>
<span>הוסף לסל</span>
</span>
</button>
<ul class="add-to-links">
<li>
<span class="separator">|</span>
<a class="link-compare" href="http://adcs.gostorego.com/catalog/product_compare/add/product/111/uenc/aHR0cDovL2FkY3MuZ29zdG9yZWdvLmNvbS8,/">הוסף להשוואה</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

now i want to find inside each li if the the price class contains = 0.00.
if it true so hide class price and also hide the div class actions.

this is my jQuery code:

```
$j('.item').each(function(){

if($j(this).find(".price:contains('0.00')")){

$j(this).find(".price:contains('0.00')").hide();

$j(this).find(".actions").hide();

}
});
```

when doing this code it is hiding the price if it's 0.00 
but when hiding the .actions it hiding all the .actions in all li obviously,
but agian i want only to hide the .price if its 0.00 and its .actions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
$('.item').each(function () {
   var zeroPrice = $(this).find(".price:contains('0.00')");
   if (zeroPrice.length > 0) {
       zeroPrice.hide();
       $(this).find(".actions").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank that worked, but if i try to do something more coplex like:$('.item').each(function () {
   var zeroPrice = $(this).find(".price:contains('0.00')");
   if (zeroPrice.length > 0) {
       zeroPrice.hide();
       $(this).find(".actions:first-child").text("wow");
   }
}); it dosent work any suggestions here?

Comment: your `first-child` is not correct I guess, see this demo: http://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/